# CakePHP 4 multiple checkboxes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I want to populate a checkbox group with the array JournalEntry[strategy][strategies_conditions]

I then want to have the checkboxes selected that are contained in JournalEntry[journal_entries_strategy_conditions]

I have the checkboxes displaying but not linked correctly to the correct fields of `name` and `id`

This is the code I have in the edit.php

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->control('journal_id', ['options' => $journals]);
    echo $this->Form->control('ticket_number');
    echo $this->Form->control('strategy_id', ['options' => $strategies, 'empty' => true, 'onChange' => 'getComboA(this)']);
    debug($journalEntry);
    ?>
    <div id="stategy-condition">
        <?php echo $this->Form->control('journal_entries_strategy_conditions.strategies_condition_id', 
            [
                'type' => 'select',
                'multiple' => 'checkbox', 
                'options' => $journalEntry[strategy][strategies_conditions],
                'selected' => $journalEntry[journal_entries_strategy_conditions] 
            ]); ?>
    </div>
```

With this I get this output, as you can see it is using the `object` for the `<label>` and `<input value="1"` is set to the `id` value

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="strategy-id">Strategy</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="strategy_id" value="">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="strategy-id-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="strategy_id[]" value="0" id="strategy-id-0">{
    "id": 1,
    "strategy_id": 5,
    "name": "zxcasd",
    "level": "0",
    "created": "2020-08-01T21:21:11+00:00",
    "modified": "2020-08-01T21:21:11+00:00"
}</label>
       </div>
       <div class="checkbox">
            <label for="strategy-id-1">
                <input type="checkbox" name="strategy_id[]" value="1" id="strategy-id-1">{
    "id": 2,
    "strategy_id": 5,
    "name": "zxcasd",
    "level": "0",
    "created": "2020-08-01T21:21:11+00:00",
    "modified": "2020-08-01T21:21:11+00:00"
}</label>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label for="strategy-id-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="strategy_id[]" value="2" id="strategy-id-2">{
    "id": 3,
    "strategy_id": 5,
    "name": "zxcad",
    "level": "0",
    "created": "2020-08-01T21:21:11+00:00",
    "modified": "2020-08-01T21:21:11+00:00"
}</label></div></div>
```

Here is the data:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\JournalEntry) {

'id' => (int) 20,
'journal_id' => (int) 1,
'ticket_number' => 'sdfsdfsdf',
'strategy_id' => (int) 5,
'timeframe' => '',
'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

    'time' => '2020-08-25 20:51:42.000000+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

},
'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

    'time' => '2020-08-25 20:51:42.000000+00:00',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

},
'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\JournalEntriesStrategyCondition) {

        'id' => (int) 8,
        'journal_entry_id' => (int) 20,
        'strategies_condition_id' => (int) 1,
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-25 20:51:42.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
        'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

            'time' => '2020-08-25 20:51:42.000000+00:00',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        
        },
    
    }
],
'strategy' => object(App\Model\Entity\Strategy) {

    'id' => (int) 5,
    'user_id' => (int) 1,
    'name' => 'zxcasd',
    'description' => 'zxcasd',
    'one_hundred_trades' => (int) 0,
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false
    
    },
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false
    
    },
    'strategies_conditions' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\StrategiesCondition) {

            'id' => (int) 1,
            'strategy_id' => (int) 5,
            'name' => 'zxcasd',
            'level' => '0',
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false
            
            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false
            
            },
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                'strategy_id' => true,
                'name' => true,
                'level' => true,
                'created' => true,
                'modified' => true,
                'strategy' => true
            ]
        
        },
        (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\StrategiesCondition) {

            'id' => (int) 2,
            'strategy_id' => (int) 5,
            'name' => 'zxcasd',
            'level' => '0',
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false
            
            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false
            
            }
        
        },
        (int) 2 => object(App\Model\Entity\StrategiesCondition) {

            'id' => (int) 3,
            'strategy_id' => (int) 5,
            'name' => 'zxcad',
            'level' => '0',
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false
            
            },
            'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

                'time' => '2020-08-01 21:21:11.000000+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false
            
            },
            
        }
    ],

},
'[new]' => false,
```

This the request date for edit.php

```
[
    'journal_id' => '1',
    'ticket_number' => 'test con',
    'pair' => '',
    'buy_sell' => '',
    'personal_notes' => '',
    'entry_date_time' => '',
    'entry_price' => '',
    'strategy_id' => '5',
    'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
        'strategies_condition_id' => [
            (int) 0 => '1'
        ]
    ],
    'timeframe' => '',
    'position_size' => '',
    'sl' => '',
    'tp' => '',
    'market_conditions' => '',
    'entry_toughts' => '',
    'close_date_time' => '',
    'close_price' => '',
    'profit' => '',
    'fees' => '',
    'high_price' => '',
    'low_price' => '',
    'exit_thoughts' => '',
    'feeling_before' => '',
    'feeling_after' => ''
]
```

add.php

```
[
    'journal_id' => '1',
    'ticket_number' => 'sdfdsf',
    'pair' => '',
    'buy_sell' => '',
    'personal_notes' => '',
    'entry_date_time' => '',
    'entry_price' => '',
    'strategy_id' => '5',
    'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'strategies_condition_id' => '2'
        ]
    ],
    'timeframe' => '',
    'position_size' => '',
    'sl' => '',
    'tp' => '',
    'market_conditions' => '',
    'entry_toughts' => '',
    'close_date_time' => '',
    'close_price' => '',
    'profit' => '',
    'fees' => '',
    'high_price' => '',
    'low_price' => '',
    'exit_thoughts' => '',
    'feeling_before' => '',
    'feeling_after' => ''
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `selected` option, the option to provide values for selection is named `val` or `value`, and like the `options` option, it expects a flat `key => value` array (there's an exception if you want to provide attributes for `<option>` elements, in that case you can use nested arrays with `text` and `value` keys).

For `options` the array key will be use for the `<option>` element's `value` attribute, and the array value will be used for the content of the element.

For `value` the array value will be used for matching against the `options` array's keys, ie AFAICT you'd need an array of `strategies_condition_id`.

Often times values for select controls are being prepared using the `list` finder, you'll see that in baked controllers. However since you have nested associations, that's not necessarily feasible, and you're possibly better of converting the data after the fact, which can easily be done using collections.

For example in your view template:

```php
<div id="stategy-condition">
    <?php echo $this->Form->control('journal_entries_strategy_conditions', [
        'type' => 'select',
        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
        'options' =>
            collection($journalEntry['strategy']['strategies_conditions'])
                ->combine('id', 'name')
                ->toArray(),
        'value' =>
            collection($journalEntry['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'])
                ->extract('strategies_condition_id')
                ->toArray()
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

The `combine()` call should build a collection like:

```php
[
    1 => 'zxcasd',
    2 => 'zxcasd',
    3 => 'zxcad',
]
```

and the `extract()` should result in a collection containing this:

```php
[
    0 => 1
]
```

which should result in the first checkbox being checked.

- **[Cookbook > Collections > combine()](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::combine)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > extract()](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::extract)**

As far as your control name problem goes, there are many ways to solve this, you could for example use a custom template where you hardcode the input name:

```php
echo $this->Form->control('journal_entries_strategy_conditions', [
    'type' => 'select',
    // ...
    'templates' => [
        'checkbox' =>
            '<input
                type="checkbox"
                name="journal_entries_strategy_conditions[][strategies_condition_id]"
                value="{{value}}"
                {{attrs}}>',
    ]
]);
```

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Options for Control](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-control)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses)**

Or transform the data before marshalling (patching), using the `beforeMarshal` callback in your `JournalEntriesTable` class:

```php
public function beforeMarshal(
    \Cake\Event\EventInterface $event,
    \ArrayObject $data,
    \ArrayObject $options
) {
    if (isset($data['journal_entries_strategy_conditions']['strategies_condition_id']) {
        $ids = $data['journal_entries_strategy_conditions']['strategies_condition_id'];
        
        $conditions = [];
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $conditions[] = [
                'strategies_condition_id' => $id,
            ];
        }
        
        $data['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'] = $conditions;
    }
}
```

This would transform the data from:

```php
'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
    'strategies_condition_id' => [
        '1',
        '2'
    ],
],
```

to:

```php
'journal_entries_strategy_conditions' => [
    [
        'strategies_condition_id' => '1'
    ],
    [
        'strategies_condition_id' => '2'
    ]
],
```

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**

Or even create the individual checkboxes manually, where you have proper control over every aspect of every form control, including the name:

```php
echo $this->Form->label('journal_entries_strategy_conditions');
echo $this->Form->hidden('journal_entries_strategy_conditions', ['value' => '']);

$selectedIds = collection($journalEntry['journal_entries_strategy_conditions'])
    ->extract('strategies_condition_id')
    ->toArray();

foreach ($journalEntry['strategy']['strategies_conditions'] as $index => $condition) {
    echo $this->Form->control(
        "journal_entries_strategy_conditions.{$index}.strategies_condition_id",
        [
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'hiddenField' => false,
            'label' => $condition['name'],
            'value' => $condition['id'],
            'checked' => in_array($condition['id'], $selectedIds, true),
        ]
    );
}
```

This would create name attributes like:

```php
journal_entries_strategy_conditions[0][strategies_condition_id]
journal_entries_strategy_conditions[1][strategies_condition_id]
...
```

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Select, Checkbox and Radio Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls)**

Comment: Thanks @ndm as always for the effort in your answer, that has really explained it. I have one issue now and that is I cant save. the `name` property of each input should be `name="journal_entries_strategy_conditions[0][strategies_condition_id]` and name="journal_entries_strategy_conditions[1][strategies_condition_id]` etc but I am only getting `name="journal_entries_strategy_conditions[strategies_condition_id][ ]` for each one. I am missing the ascending numbers. Also on a side note. I am not sure how CakePHP will handle deleting the associated record if I untick a checkbox.

Comment: @KeithPower Well, that's quite a bit different than the initial problem. What behavior exactly are you looking for when saving with unticked checkboxes?

Comment: sorry I might be confusing the issue by asking two questions. To keep it simple and close this question fully I just need to fix the issue of the format of the checkbox names `name="journal_entries_strategy_conditions[strategies_condition_id]` they should be in the formation of `name="journal_entries_strategy_conditions[0][strategies_condition_id]` This is causing and error when saving. The saving/deleting with unticked checkboxes is a separate issue.

Comment: I have added the `$this->request->getData()` for `add.php` which I hard code the checkboxes. This saves fine. If you look at the output for the `edit.php` you see that `'journal_entries_strategy_conditions'` structure is wrong. I have tried `<?php echo $this->Form->control('journal_entries_strategy_conditions[]strategies_condition_id'`

Comment: looking at the docs https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.View.Widget.MultiCheckboxWidget.html#63-121 `* - `name` The name attribute of the inputs to create.
 69:      *   `[]` will be appended to the name.` I wonder how to override this as it dosnt work with associated data

Comment: @KeithPower I've updated my answer with a few examples of how to solve this.